# Discord Rewrite Bot not working after deploying on Heroku

Tags: python, heroku, discord.py

It used to work fine so far both in heroku and locally. Now it only works locally but doesn't work aftter deploying on heroku. This is the log from Heroku:

```
2021-04-22T17:41:34.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2021-04-22T17:41:37.853181+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Starting process with command `python3.9.4 dbot.py`
2021-04-22T17:41:38.485331+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from starting to up
2021-04-22T17:41:39.356992+00:00 app[worker.1]: bash: python3.9.4: command not found
2021-04-22T17:41:39.416346+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Process exited with status 127
2021-04-22T17:41:39.485205+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from up to crashed
```

I have my requirments.txt file with these dependencies included:

```
git+https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py
youtube_dl==2020.03.08
pynacl == 1.3.0
colorlog == 4.1.0
```

And I have this in my procfile:

```
worker: python3.9.4 dbot.py
```

As for my knowledge I think it has something do with the python version which I recently updated to 3.9.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of putting the version of python into the `Procfile` simply put:

```
worker: python dbot.py
```

If you want to specify a python version for your bot create a `runtime.txt` file with the following format

```
python-3.9.4
```